# In above code i just used code for four order of series i want to convert this for n series like next code

Tags: python

I have this code for four order expansion of series :

```
d=[]  
for i in range(3,51):  
     d.append(C[0][0] + C[0][1]/(i-do)**2 + C[0][2]/(i-do)**4 + C[0][3]/(i-do)**6)
```

I just wanna convert above code for nth number of series mean if i my data is long upto five order my code run program to `C[0][4]/(i-do)**8`

```
d=[]  
for i in range(3,51):  
    d.append(C[0][0] + C[0][1]/(i-do)**2 + C[0][2]/(i-do)**4 + C[0][3]/(i-do)**6 + '''and soo on to''' + C[0][r]/(i-do)**2n )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like this?

```py
d=[]
n=5 # change to whatever number you want
for i in range(3,51):  
    d.append(sum(C[0][k]/(i-do)**(2*k) for k in range(n)))
```